# VHDL delayed assignment problem

Tags: vhdl

I want output to equal "11111111" on the first rising edge of the clock but it only happens on the second rising edge when I test the code with ModelSim. The code might look weird as a simplification of a more complex design where I have the same kind of problem.

code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity delay is
port(
clock : in STD_LOGIC;
output : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) := "00000000"
);
end delay;
architecture behavioral of delay is
signal debug : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
begin
process(clock)
begin
if rising_edge(clock) then
    debug <= "0000";
    case debug is
        when "0000" => output <= "11111111";
        when others => output <= "00000000";
    end case;
end if;
end process;
end behavioral;
```

testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity eentestbench is
end eentestbench;
architecture behavioral of eentestbench is
signal clock : STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal result: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
component delay
port(
    clock : in STD_LOGIC;
    output : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)
);
end component;
begin
uut : delay port map(
clock => clock,
output => result
);
stim_process: process
begin
clock <= '0';
wait for 1 ns;
clock <= '1';
wait for 1 ns;
end process;
end behavioral;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `debug` assignment outside the if statement with the condition `rising_edge(clock)`.

In the following waveform you can see it's not assigned until the first clock edge and the `output` assignment is dependent on `debug`.

[image: eentestbench.png]
*(clickable)*

The `debug` assignment could just as easily be a concurrent statement or have initial value supplied by a generic.