# VHDL: value isn't assigned immediately

Tags: vhdl

I asked a similar question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/177902/vhdl-delayed-assignment-problem/177928#177928). I thought that that answer would be applicable to this code but I have the same problem. I have a ROM that runs at twice the speed of my CPU (left out all the commands except 'OUT' to make it easier to understand). The reason it runs at twice the speed is because the ROM has a pipeline.

The first value in my ROM is '0xF100' which would execute the 'OUT' instruction. For debugging purposes I let my 'OUT' instruction set 'output' to "11111111". When I simulate the design with ModelSim I find that 'output' doesn't get set to "11111111" immediately but instead needs another rising edge of 'ClockDivided' to set its value. I want 'output' to get it's value immediately, how do I do this?

code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
entity first is
port(
input : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
output : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
PCout : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0) := "0000000000000000";
clock : in STD_LOGIC
);
end first;

architecture behavioral of first is
signal PC : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
signal data : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0) := "0000000000000000";
signal regC : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "0000";
signal regA : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "0000";
signal regB : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "0000";
signal opcode : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := "0000";
type registerFile is array(15 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal registers : registerFile := (others => "00000000");
signal clockDivided : STD_LOGIC := '1';
component rom is
port(
    address : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
    q : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    clock : in STD_LOGIC := '1'
);
end component;
begin
rom_inst : rom PORT MAP (
        address => PC,
        clock => clock,
        q => data
        );  
PCout <= data;
process(clock)
begin
if rising_edge(clock) then
    clockDivided <= not(clockDivided); --dividing the clock because the ROM runs twice as fast
end if;
end process;
process(clockDivided)
begin
opcode <= data(15 downto 12);
regC <= data(11 downto 8);
regA <= data(7 downto 4);
regB <= data(3 downto 0);
if rising_edge(clockDivided) then   
    registers(0) <= "00000000";
    case opcode is
        when "1111" => output <= "11111111"; --output doesn't get set to "11111111" immediately                                 
        PC <= PC + 1;
        --OUT
        when others =>
        PC <= PC + 1;
        end case;
    end if;
end process;
end behavioral;
```

testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity testbench is
end testbench;

architecture behavioral of testbench is
signal inputX : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
signal outputX : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0) := "00000000";
signal PCX : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
signal clockX : STD_LOGIC := '0';
component first
port(
    input : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
    output : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
    PCout : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
    clock : in STD_LOGIC
);
end component;
begin
uut: first port map(
    input => inputX,
    output => outputX,
    PCout => PCX,
    clock => clockX
);
stim_proc: process
begin
    clockX <= '0';
    wait for 1 ns;
    clockX <= '1';
    wait for 1 ns;
end process;
end behavioral;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the following code:

```
process(clockDivided)
begin
    opcode <= data(15 downto 12);
    regC <= data(11 downto 8);
    regA <= data(7 downto 4);
    regB <= data(3 downto 0);
    if rising_edge(clockDivided) then
        --
    end if;
end process;
```

The process sensitivity list only has `clockDivided` present. When `data` changes as part of the ROM being read, the process is not run; only when the next event on `clockDivided` occurs does this happen, so your `opcode` won't change until that point either. This is what causes your delay.

The easiest thing is to move the concurrent assignments like `opcode <= data(15 downto 12);` outside of the process. you could equally add `data` to the sensitivity list, but there is really no need for those statements to be in the process in the first place.

---

Additionally, from my experience, it is a good idea to move the extraction of various program word fields from a std_logic_vector into a function. The function accepts the program word as a parameter, and returns a record type that contains your 'decoded' instruction. Something like:

```
type INSTRUCTION_type is record (
    opcode : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    regA : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    regB : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    regC : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
end record;

function from_slv(v : std_logic_vector) return INSTRUCTION_type is
    variable rv : INSTRUCTION_type;
begin
    rv.opcode := v(15 downto 0);
    rv.regA := v(7 downto 4);
    rv.regB := v(3 downto 0);
    rv.regC := v(11 downto 8);
    return rv;
end function;
```

Then in your entity:

```
program_word <= from_slv(data_out);
```

...

```
case (program_word.opcode) is
```

etc

This allows you to have the interpretation of the program word in one easily changeable place in a package. The record allows the various program word elements to be easily connected between entities, pipelined, etc. this technique also makes it very easy to add more elements to the program word, without having to change entity port declarations and instantiations.

Comment: I tried both moving the concurrent statements outside the process and including 'data' to the sensitivity list of ClockDivided's process. Both don't seem to work. Any thoughts? Also, thanks for the record idea.

Comment: You mentioned that your ROM is pipelined; presumably you are already taking the extra cycle delay from this into account?

Comment: This could be the problem but I don't see where it could go wrong. The ROM is generated by Altera's MegaWizard. The ROM runs twice as fast as the CPU. 1 cycle is used to load the data into some data registers and at cycle 2 the data is available.

Comment: Can you see that `opcode` becomes valid at the right time?

Comment: Yes it gets the right value ("1111")

Comment: OK but does this happen before the edge where you expect the output to be valid

Comment: opcode gets its value at clock cycle 1 and output gets its value at clock cycle 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25363/discussion-between-scary-jeff-and-gilianzz).

Comment: I think I can solve the problem by using variables where needed. Would something like  
opcode := data(15 downto 12);  
regC := data(11 downto 8);
execute in parallel or not?

Comment: Nope, didn't work

Comment: They are not concurrent statements unless they are outside the process. A process is comprised of sequential statements.

Comment: sorry @gilianzz I couldn't log into the chat after all. If you moved the assignment of `opcode` outside of the process, there's no way that this could happen one clock cycle after `data` becomes valid; the signals should be the same.

Comment: @scary_jeff data becomes valid at the first rising edge of ClockDivided which means that the case statement isn't checking the right value of opcode I think. Does this mean that I have to run my ROM at 4x the speed of the CPU?

Comment: Yes, or you could experiment with delaying `ClockDivided`, so that its rising edge happens sufficiently after `clock` to meet any setup time. You could use `clockDivided <= not(clockDivided) after 5 ns;` to try this out, but in hardware you'll have to use a PLL of some sort. This could start to get complicated and I think further discussion would be outside the scope of this question; the original problem seems to be well understood at this point.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. Apparently the ROM's output would go through an output register first. I removed this register and now everything works fine. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You originally said that it was a pipelined ROM, so I would expect there to be a register of this type. If you don't need the performance the pipeline adds, then removing it sounds like a good idea